# Ember.js model- and setupController-hook with nested routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm currently evaluating Ember.js and therefore I am building a small sample app. Currently everything went quite smooth so far, but now I don't seem to be able to fix my last little problem.

When I access the app normaly via the route films, everything works as expected. The list of films is displayed. Now when I click onto a film, the details of the film are loaded via `setupController` hook just below the list of films. That's all just fine.

Here comes my problem: I would like to be able to access the film details directly via url, but somehow in this case another request is fired to grab the film details, with the value of `undefinded`. As far as I understand that is the `model` hook.

I can only guess, but I think it is the `model` hook which is beeing executed.

Can someone point me to the probably obvious mistake I'm making? And on the other hand, is the code i wrote so far "correct"? Or is there a better way of doing this?

(I am aware of the bad way I use to render the film details. I will remove the `{{#each}}` tag, and change the way I asign the response to the `film` variable.

Here the link to the sample app: http://jsbin.com/ewiN/1#/films

**UPDATE**

**Ok, now I am getting really confused. I almost have it working, hopefully someone can point it out to me, because it's such a simple task, but it nearly seems impossible to do without knowing ember really well...
When accessing the app via url, it only works when I remove the `setupController` hook. But I need that hook, to load the `FilmDetails` on clicking onto the links to properly load the `FilmDetails`.**

http://jsbin.com/ewiN/16#/films/tt0100669

Many thanks for the feedback!
Regards
Reto

Comment: This was a problem in Ember because the url transitions and the transitionTo were not being handled uniformly. This has changed. Take a look at the gist:  https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I could not figure out how this is going to help me. I'm using RC7, does this problem still exist there? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `jQuery.getJSON`, use `Ember.RSVP.Promise`, because internally ember use this promise api instead of jquery. I think that using both, can make inconsistencies.

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      

  var films = [];

  jQuery.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + searchTerm, function (response) {                

    $.each(response.Search, function (index, value) {
      films.pushObject(Kitag.Films.create({
        title: value.Title,
        id: value.imdbID
      }));
    });
  }).fail(reject);

  resolve(films);
});
```

Because we are returning a promise instead of an object, we need to use the model hook, because it is wait until the promise is resolve to render templates.

```
Kitag.FilmsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Kitag.Films.getMovies('spiderman');
  }
});
```

I have removed the `Kitag.FilmRoute`, because the expected:

```
Kitag.FilmRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return Kitag.Film.find(params.id)
    },
    serialize: function (model) {
        return { film_id: model.get("id") };
    }
});
```

is the default.

This is the final result http://jsbin.com/ewiN/15/edit

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, now almost everything is working. There still is a problem: somehow when clicking on a link, it now uses the Kitag.Films model instead of the Kitag.Film. It is not requesting the Film resource via ajax, because the Films model is already loaded i guess. I assume I am not using the {{#linkTo}} helper properly. any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi. I have changed the router, please give a look in the jsbin.

Comment: I'm afraid this was not what I meant. Everything was just fine, before, except that it did load the films model instead of the actual film model (with more infomration about the film)
So in http://jsbin.com/ewiN/10/edit we only need to fix the model issue.

Comment: please have a look at the update in the question, and the updated code: http://jsbin.com/ewiN/16#/films/tt0100669